# Global variables in pure functional languages

Tags: functional-programming, programming-languages

Does a pure functional language loses its purity if global variables are allowed?
I mean does having global variables affect the **referential transparency** of the language?

I suppose not, because of **value semantics** but I'm not sure and would like to
know what other people think.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science, not practical programming. Try cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. Didn't know about that page.

Comment: In functional languages you can pass functions, thus + can be considered a global variable in Haskell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a pure functional language, "variable" means something different than what it usually means in imperative languages. It is not variable in the sense that it can be reassigned within a given scope, but rather in the sense that each time it comes into scope, it may have a different value. But for the lifetime of that scope it remains constant. So for example, in the function

```
f x y = x + y
```

`x` and `y` are variables which become bound when `f` is applied to them. Once bound, they never change within the scope of that invocation, they simply go out of scope at some point. Other invocations will bind `x` and `y` to different values. That is the sense in which functional variables "vary", which is closer (some might say identical) to the original mathematical meaning of a variable.

So, to your question: do global variables ruin purity? No, because global variables, since they never go out of scope, are effectively *constants*.

Answer (score 1):

Mutable variables don't break referential transparency as long as reading/writing them happens in a scope that allows side effects. For example, in Haskell, the most basic type of mutable variables is [`IORef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-IORef.html). Passing an `IORef` around doesn't break referential transparency. And reading or writing `IORef`s is only allowed within the `IO` monad.